# "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name" no effect in Confluent 5.0.1

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have upgraded from confluent 4.0.1 to confluent 5.0.1 recently. The bootstrap.server's version is Kafka 1.0. 
In my HBaseSink Connector, I have configured the new feature ""errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name" as follows:

> {
>   "name": "kafka-hbase4",
>   "config": {
>       "connector.class": "com.xxxx.hbase.sink.HBaseSinkConnector",
>       ....
>       "zookeeper.quorum": "xxxx:2181",
>       "topics": "oplog_demo.hbase_test1",
>       "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name":"error-topic-1"
>   }
>   }

the program normally works O.K. However, when I send some error messages to the topic of the HBase Sink Connector, like some Chineses words "哈哈哈", the program goes down, throwing a SerializationException, and no messages are consumed by the "error-topic-1".

Does that mean the configuration "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name" not working? How come could that be and how can I make this configuration work?

Comment: Not clear what serializers you are using, but the StringSerializer expects UTF-8 data, no matter what topic you've configured

Comment: @cricket_007 I am using the default "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter". Actually, I'm expecting a serialization exception and the message can be sent to the deadletterqueue topic, but what baffles me is nothing happens.

Comment: I haven't used the DLQ feature, but I think it still tries to apply a serializer to those messages to send to the other topic rather than just copy the raw bytes

Comment: this problem is due to my java classpath set wrong. After I set the right path, problem solved.

Comment: Cool. Feel free to provide the full solution below as an answer rather than a comment

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that error tolerance is set correctly

```
"errors.tolerance": "all"
```

This is a really good resource for DLQ configuration [Connecting to Apache Kafka
Kafka Connect Deep Dive – Error Handling and Dead Letter Queues](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-error-handling-dead-letter-queues/)